# Is there an equivalent query sql to oracle using resources files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, resources

**sql query into Resources Files**

I start work with Oracle and i need know if  this solution can be apply in Oracle query.

**SQL VERSION**

**Resource:**
 select value1, value2, value3 from mytable order by **{0}**  **{1}**

**code:**

```
 using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand((contactId == 0 ? String.Format(Resource.SqlScripts.List, **orderByField**, **orderByDirection**)
 {
```

.
 .
 .

there is a equivalent Oracle query  using resources querys ?

Comment: This isn't really specific to Oracle or SQL, its about strings. Yes.

Comment: I think eddie is asking if Oracle order by works the same as MS Sql order by. It does.

Comment: Thanks  Andrew Walters ... I was doing wrong. Was passing order by column and order by direction as parameters, ho God.. and this is same for Oracle and Sql

Comment: "This isn't really specific to Oracle or SQL, its about strings" tanks Soner  exactly you open my eyes.